# Installed MPI but still linker error LNK2019 appears

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mpi, lnk2019

I've installed MS-MPIv5 from Microsoft and also the debugger for msmpi. In proejct properties in VS2012, I've changed C/C++ -> Additional include libraries adding "$(MSMPI_INC); $(MSMPI_INC)\x64" and also Linker -> All options->Additional Dependencies adding "msmpi.lib;", but VS is still giving me al lot of linker errors such as

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MPI_Barrier@4

unresolved external symbol _MPI_Bcast@20

and so on, with all the mpi functions or type of variables. Is there something I forgot to change or add?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Did the installer set the MSMPI_INC environment variable? Have you tried using an absolute reference to msmpi.lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used 2012, but if it's similar to the older versions of VS then **[this detailed link](http://web.archive.org/web/20201017201425/https://sites.google.com/site/master1hd/software/mpi-with-visual-studio-2005-2008)** may help. In general make sure to do these 3 things:

1. Add the "Additional **Include** Directories"
2. Add the "Additional **Library** Directories"
3. Add the "Additional **Dependencies**" (msimpi.lib)

It sounds like you may be missing the 2nd step?

Comment: Thank you, I followed the guide and it worked; so, it does work for VS2012. What I was missing was adding the path where the SDK's files where installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try **$(MSMPI_INC)x64** (no \)
In my PC

```
MSMPI_INC=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include\
```